# Socket.io cannot be loaded when Ionic is emulated inside Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, socket.io

First of all, let me show you the error I am getting:

[image]

My index.html:

```
<script src="http://demo.myapp.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js""></script>
```

My socket.js

```
this.socket = io.connect(`//${Config.get("domain")}:${Config.get("port")}`);
Resolves to //demo.myapp.com:8080
```

My config.xml

```
...
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
...
```

`cordova-plugin-whitelist` is added to my application.

```
Plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" already installed on android.
```

When I try:

```
ionic run android
```

My phone which is connected via USB to my computer opens the application successfully. However, when I inspect the console logs via Chrome I see the error message I posted at the top of this post.

I searched on Google about this issue and tried everything but nothing works.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your white list plugin is not compatible with your cordova android platform.I resolved it after updating both the plugin and android platform

Comment: Update your platform using this cordova platform add android and check if this is the latest version you can also do cordova platform add android@5.2.2
To update the plugins do npm install -g cordova-check-plugins and then use this command cordova-check-plugins --update=auto

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. A bit unrelated but it may help to future visitors.

Make sure you give the full prefix, like so:

```
<script src="http://yourapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js">
```

instead of

```
<script src="//yourapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js">
```